# How to select rows by range comparison in SQL Server?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have following table named `T` in left as source table.

[image]

FINAL OUTPUT SHOULD BE AS FOLLOWING,

[image]

I want to take only those rows where `Actual` value is in between `Basic`, associated with the `Model` and `Level` columns.

For example if you take `Model = HT65`, the `Actual` value of 23.2 lies between `Basic = 22 & 24`, so that row should be selected where `Basic = 24`. i.e highlighted in yellow, same is true for JF97. Here you can refer right hand side table as reference result.

For the same model, if `Actual` is 21,  the first row should be chosen, with `level = 1`, like this:

[image]

If **Actual** column value is more than value in **Basic** **Level** should be marked as ***out*** highlighted in orange, as following,

[image]

I have not tried it as it seemed complex to me. your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple union.  While there are more complex ways to do this, this flow allows you to see the two separate comparisons easily and tweak as needed.

select model,level,actual from T

where actual between level and basic

union

select model,level,'out' from T

where actual > basic

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.*, t2.level
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.model = t.model and t2.basic >= t.actual
      order by t2.level asc
     ) t2;
```

Note that this returns `NULL` rather than the string `'out'`.  Mixing strings and numbers complicates the query because of the conversion logic.